# Are Free monads are Church numerals?

Tags: monads, free-monad, church-encoding

A commentator [recently stated](https://twitter.com/KenScambler/status/679281114582663169):

> Free monads are Church numerals -- just using (endo-) functors instead of functions!

He goes on [to explain this](https://twitter.com/KenScambler/status/679552842777010176) saying:

> they are both an endofunct(ion|or) composed 0 - n times

I get that Church Numerals are a set of anonymous function compositions, with a composition for each number. I just don't see how that applies to Free Monads.

My question is: **Are Free monads are Church numerals?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort of.

A generalization of Church numerals is where the numeral `n` is `f^n` where `f` is an endomorphism (an arrow whose domain and codomain is the same object) in some [category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory) and `f^n` means "compose `f` with itself `n` times". The ordinary Church numerals are in the category of *sets* where the arrows are *functions*, so e.g. the numeral `3` applied to `f` and `x` is `f(f(f(x)))`. For example if `f(x) = x + 10`, then `3 f 0` is `30`.

In a category of *categories*, the arrows are *functors*. There, the numeral `3` applied to some functor `f` and object `x` (for example, a type), is again `f(f(f(x)))`. If `f` is e.g. the type constructor `f x = Int => x`, then `3 f String` is `Int => Int => Int => String`, the type of functions that take three `Int` arguments and return a `String`.

Now, for a functor `f`, `Free f` is the *free monad* generated by `f`, where an instance of the type `Free f x` is either just an `x` or an `f (Free f x)`. So it will have a type of the form `f(f(f(...(x)))`, a composition of zero or more `f`s applied to `x`.

So it's not that "free monads are Church numerals", but that a free monad is a type construction on some functor, and the Church numerals on that functor embed in that type.